# How to concat SQL queries in @NamedNativeQueries with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement, where I want to pass dynamic schema name inside `@NamedNativeQueries` annotation. As follows:

```java
@NamedNativeQueries( { @NamedNativeQuery(name = ExampleEntity.example, query = "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM schema.tablename where col1=?", resultSetMapping = "ExampleEntity") })
```

In above code `schema.tablename`, I want to pass in place of `schema`: `schema1.tablename`, `schema2.tablename`, `schema3.tablename` and so on, where `schema1`, `schema2`, ... are from background when I'm calling this named native entity.

Comment: Neither JDBC, nor JPA allows passing identifiers as parameters. You either need to have multiple queries for each situation or use a CriteriaBuilder, where you'd still have to hard-code select the correct class by the given parameter. Your other option is to leave yourself open to SQL injection and try to avert it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm already using multiple queries for each situation, but it is static that's why I'm looking for better solution.